# match subdomain for a redirect

Tags: php, regex, redirect, preg-match

I want to match a subdomain that is in the PHP variable `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` and then do a internal redirect. Apache or nginx rewrites is not a option because this are external rewrites that are visible to the client/user.

My regular expression is `(.*(?<!^.))subdomain\.example\.com` as you can see I match a subdomain in a subdomain (multi-level subdomains). The first capture group would I like to use for later.

This is my PHP code:

```php
if(preg_match('#(.*(?<!^.))subdomain\.example\.com#', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], $match1)) {
    echo $match1[1] . 'anothersubdomain.example.com';
}
```

But this will fail if the subdomain is for example `csssubdomain.example.com` because this is another subdomain that I don't want to match. With the following PHP script I test the matches:

```php
$tests = array(
    'subdomain.example.com' => 'anothersubdomain.example.com',
    'css.subdomain.example.com' => 'css.anothersubdomain.example.com',
    'csssubdomain.example.com' => 'csssubdomain.example.com',
    'tsubdomain.example.com' => 'tsubdomain.example.com',
    'multi.sub.subdomain.example.com' => 'multi.sub.anothersubdomain.example.com',
    '.subdomain.example.com' => '.subdomain.example.com',
);

foreach( $tests as $test => $correct_answer) {
        $result = preg_replace( '#(.*(?<!^.))subdomain\.example\.com#', '$1anothersubdomain.example.com', $test);
    echo 'Input:    ' . $test . "\n" . 
         'Expected: ' . $correct_answer . "\n" . 
         'Actual  : ' .$result . "\n";
    $passorfail =  (strcmp( $result, $correct_answer) === 0 ? "PASS\n\n" : "FAIL\n\n");
    echo $passorfail;
}
```

You'd get [as output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/xRzW4c):

```
Input:    subdomain.example.com
Expected: anothersubdomain.example.com
Actual  : anothersubdomain.example.com
PASS

Input:    css.subdomain.example.com
Expected: css.anothersubdomain.example.com
Actual  : css.anothersubdomain.example.com
PASS

Input:    csssubdomain.example.com
Expected: csssubdomain.example.com
Actual  : cssanothersubdomain.example.com
FAIL

Input:    tsubdomain.example.com
Expected: tsubdomain.example.com
Actual  : tsubdomain.example.com
PASS

Input:    multi.sub.subdomain.example.com
Expected: multi.sub.anothersubdomain.example.com
Actual  : multi.sub.anothersubdomain.example.com
PASS

Input:    .subdomain.example.com
Expected: .subdomain.example.com
Actual  : .subdomain.example.com
PASS
```

The strange thing is that it does match `csssubdomain.example.com` but not `tsubdomain.example.com`.

Does someone know what regular expression you can use for this case? I've tried some things with  [lookahead and lookbehind zero-width assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) but it didn't really work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this pattern:

```
~^((?:\w+\.)*?)subdomain\.example\.com~
```

if you allow this `.toto.subdomain.example.com`, just add `\.?` at the beginning:

```
~^((?:\.?\w+\.)*?)subdomain\.example\.com~
```

if you want to allow a hyphen character just add it to the character class:

```
~^((?:\.?[\w-]+\.)*?)subdomain\.example\.com~
```

and if you don't allow substring to begin or ending with a hypen character:

```
~^((?:\.?\w+([\w-]*?\w)?\.)*?)subdomain\.example\.com~
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly! Only 1 thing what about a subdomain with the 'hyphen character' (te-st.example.com)? See: http://regexr.com?34ose